# how to insert DB values on JS function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to insert values ​​from `PHP` query DB to .js echart page, how do I transfer this data, so I can do the graph?

I want to count the waiting requests, transport to the `Javascript` responsible for the creation of the graph

I'm a programming beginner and I enjoy learning, I'm not a professional and I did not study it at school.
Thanks for all the help and understanding.

**phpquery.php :**

```html
<?php
\\query get data from bd

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\dist\includes\\';
$file = $path . 'db.connect.php';
include($file);
$tec=$_SESSION['nome'];
$permi = $_SESSION['permisson'];
if($permi == "Técnico"){ $sql = "SELECT * FROM npedido WHERE estado = 'Novo' and (tec1 ='$tec' or tec2 ='$tec')";}else if($permi == "Administrador"){ $sql = "SELECT * FROM npedido WHERE estado = 'Novo'";}
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
  $contador_pedidos_novos = 0;
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
       $contador_pedidos_novos++;
    }

     
    
    ?>
```

i want to put the result inside value: "`{value:**<--mydata-->**, name:'New'}`"

**dataload.js**

```js
/*****E-Charts function start*****/
var echartsConfig = function() { 
 

 if( $('#e_chart_3').length > 0 ){
  var eChart_3 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('e_chart_3'));
  var option3 = {
   tooltip : {
    trigger: 'item',
    formatter: "{a} <br/>{b} : {c} ({d}%)",
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(33,33,33,1)',
    borderRadius:0,
    padding:10,
    textStyle: {
     color: '#fff',
     fontStyle: 'normal',
     fontWeight: 'normal',
     fontFamily: "'Roboto', sans-serif",
     fontSize: 12
    } 
   },
   legend: {
    show:true
   },
   toolbox: {
    show : true,
   },
   calculable : true,
   itemStyle: {
     normal: {
      shadowBlur: 5,
      shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
     }
   },
   series : [
    {
     name:'Advertising',
     type:'pie',
     radius : '60%',
     center : ['50%', '50%'],
     roseType : 'radius',
     color: ['#119dd2', '#d36ee8', '#667add'],
     label: {
      normal: {
       fontFamily: "'Roboto', sans-serif",
       fontSize: 12
      }
     },
     data:[
      {value:25, name:'New'},
      {value:25, name:'Close'},
      {value:50, name:'Hold'},
     ].sort(function (a, b) { return a.value - b.value; }),
    },
   ],
   animationType: 'scale',
   animationEasing: 'elasticOut',
   animationDelay: function (idx) {
    return Math.random() * 1000;
   } 
  };
  eChart_3.setOption(option3);
  eChart_3.resize();
 }
}
/*****E-Charts function end*****/
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the result from your php query to be used in your js function. To do this, you can put your php result inside a js variable and the run the function with the varible.

Comment: @Simpson, hi and tanks for reply.

Can you give me one exemple of that please?

Comment: ex. var TEST = <?php $test = "testing"; echo $test; ?>

Comment: @Simpson, i putht that inside my js.file?, if yes, i got error on that...dont alow php.

Comment: Ah I thought it was a html5 file with js within. In that case you can then use AJAX to request data from your php file

Comment: @Simpson right, i forgot that, but ... if i put "data: {
            name: $('#teste').val()," that will get the val inside <?php $teste ?> ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is in the php file create variable whit the datacontent from query then add this line`

```js
<script type="text/javascript">var teste = "<?= $teste ?>";</script>
```

on .js file just  add the variable name to data field:

```js
<--other code-->
data:[
      {value:25, name:teste},
      <--other code-->
```